# Why does the Select statement stalls when executed directly in sequence?

Tags: mysql, innodb, select, temporary-tables

When executing the following in workbench or in code, the Drop table/Create Table works ok. The Select statement stalls when executed in one go.
If the table is MyIsam, it works ok. If executed  [edited] the very first time a  few seconds later (5-10s) it executes in 15 ms, no cache involved.
Anyone can explain this behaviour ?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_vlanendpoints;
CREATE TABLE tmp_vlanendpoints (
  routeId INTEGER,
  INDEX routeId (routeId)
)
SELECT 
  routeId,
  HostNameOrIp,
  CONCAT(
      HostNameOrIp,
      '»ifIndex=',
      IFNULL(subIfIndex,ifIndex)
  ) AS port_sourcerefcode,
  nodeType
FROM tmp_getdatamultipointtrails
WHERE nodeType='PE' 
    OR (numEDDs=1 AND nodeType='EDD')
    OR (numEDDs=0 AND nodeType='AGG' AND linkId IS NULL);

# Failing SELECT when executed in sequence. Takes 15 ms if executed alone.
SELECT 
    veacpe.HostNameOrIp AS cpe_a,
    veacpe.port_sourcerefcode AS port_acpe,
    veape.HostNameOrIp AS pe_a,
    veape.port_sourcerefcode AS port_ape,
    vezcpe.HostNameOrIp AS cpe_z,
    vezcpe.port_sourcerefcode AS port_zcpe,
    vezpe.HostNameOrIp AS pe_z,
    vezpe.port_sourcerefcode AS port_zpe,
    evc.*
FROM tmp_evcdata evc
JOIN tmp_vlanendpoints veacpe ON veacpe.routeId=evc.routeId_a AND veacpe.nodeType<>'PE'
JOIN tmp_vlanendpoints veape ON veape.routeId=evc.routeId_a AND veape.nodeType='PE'
JOIN tmp_vlanendpoints vezcpe ON vezcpe.routeId=evc.routeId_z AND vezcpe.nodeType<>'PE'
JOIN tmp_vlanendpoints vezpe ON vezpe.routeId=evc.routeId_z AND vezpe.nodeType='PE';
```

SHOW CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE `tmp_getdatamultipointtrails` (
   `routeId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `linkId` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
   `deviceId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `nodeType` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
   `numEDDs` decimal(23,0) DEFAULT NULL,
   `numLooseEnds` decimal(23,0) DEFAULT NULL,
   `leafNE` text,
   `numNEs` bigint(21) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `missingTopology` text,
   `vlanId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `CIR` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `SourceRefCode` text,
   `HostNameOrIp` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   `serverTrailSourceRefCode` text,
   `entPhysicalIndex` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `ifIndex` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `subIfIndex` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

> count(*): 19733
>   select * from tmp_getdatamultipointtrails limit 2;

```
17 1340    821 PE  1   0   [3122]  3   ''  926 9984    PE821»if284»vlan926 89.13.237.13    10.25.153.4»ifIndex=6»to:89.13.237.133»ifIndex=284  17105425    284 576
17  4701    3122    EDD 1   0   [3122]  3   '' 926  9984    PE821»if284»vlan926    10.250.153.3 10.25.153.3»ifIndex=17»to:10.25.153.3»ifIndex=101720064     7001    101720064   NULL
```

Comment: " If executed a few seconds later (5-10s) it executes in 15 ms" - very likely because intermediate query results were still sitting in cache when you ran the query the second time.

Comment: Please post `SHOW CREATE TABLE tmp_getdatamultipointtrails` and `select count(*) from tmp_getdatamultipointtrails` and `select * from tmp_getdatamultipointtrails limit 2`.

Comment: @VictorDiLeo it's not possible to have such a magic cache in MySQL

Comment: I should not have used "intermediate" in my comment, but query cache is certainly available in MySQL: 1) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-cache-operation.html    2) https://www.percona.com/blog/2015/01/02/the-mysql-query-cache-how-it-works-and-workload-impacts-both-good-and-bad/   3) Googling "mysql query runs faster second time cache" will show this is a common question.

Comment: As edited, no cache is involved. We have to wait 5-10s that the initial create table finished something, otherwise it stalls completely.

Comment: @Jean-PierreB when you say it is fast, is the test just "CREATE TABLE, wait 10sec, run SELECT" ?

Comment: The `CREATE TABLE AS` you show us has a mismatch in the number of columns. Please correct it. Also, does the table have no PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: Ok, cleaned the data to be readable. Yes, indeed.

Comment: No primary keys are defined for the tmp_getdatamultipointtrails. And yes, with the sequence DROP>CREATE>WAIT 10s>SELECT, it works in 30ms.

Comment: Change the index to `INDEX (routeId, nodeType)`

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - The `CREATE .. AS SELECT` does not need to specify all columns, only the overrides and extras.